# type checking for math.isclose()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Basically i got below warning in PyCharm in the statement `math.isclose(a_val, b_val)`

`Expected type 'SupportsFloat', got 'Number' instead`

Minimal, reproducible example as below.

```py
from numbers import Number
import math

a_val = '123'
b_val = 123.4

if isinstance(a_val, Number) and isinstance(b_val, Number):
    is_close = math.isclose(a_val, b_val, abs_tol=0.5)
```

In reality, `a_val` and `b_val` are sourced somewhere else which could return float, integer or string. If both `a_val` and `b_val` are numeric, I want to check if they are almost equal. Otherwise just ignore it if any of them is string.

Question - what is the best way of type checking before passing `a_val` and `b_val` to `math.isclose()` ? What change should be done to clear the PyCharm wanring?

Comment: Looks to be an edge-case in the PyCharm type-checker. It's giving the warning because `a_val` is actually a string, but since the `math.isclose` call is inside the if-statement `a_val` must be a `Number` to go there in the first place. These two cases are mutually exclusive & I suspect the type-checker got confused. The call itself is actually unreachable. So the warning should not matter.

Comment: @rdas: No, PyCharm actually understands what's going on, but `Number` is the wrong type to check for.

Comment: @user2357112 If you make `a_val` an `int` then the warning goes away. How is that possible?

Comment: @rdas: Probably because `int` is a valid type to pass to `math.isclose`. (If you're arguing that PyCharm shouldn't type-check the `if` body at all with `a_val = '123'` because it's unreachable, I would argue that unreachable code should still be type-checked. Also, the static type checker probably just remembers "`isinstance(a_val, str)`" instead of "`type(a_val) is str`", so it thinks `a_val` could be an instance of some `str`/`Number` multiple inheritance subclass in the `if` body.)

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm that would explain it. But it seems weird to throw that warning in an unreachable code block instead of warning that the code block is unreachable in the first place. Priorities.

Comment: @rdas maybe it would be a better illustration if we put `a_val = ['123', 123][1]` instead, PyCharm still throws warning even it's reachable and the type of `a_val` is `int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`math.isclose` *doesn't support* arbitrary `Number` instances. Like most `math` functions, `math.isclose` needs arguments that can be converted to `float`. A `Number` could be something like `1+2j`, which can't be converted to `float`. (Also, `str` doesn't count - it has to be something with a `__float__` method.)

I was going to suggest using `typing.SupportsFloat`, but it looks like I misread the code, and `typing.SupportsFloat` doesn't support `isinstance` checks. If your only options are `str`, `float`, and `int`, it's probably simplest to just check for `float` and `int`, or to go the other way and just reject `str`:

```
if isinstance(a_val, (float, int)) and isinstance(b_val, (float, int)):
    ...
```

or

```
if not isinstance(a_val, str) and not isinstance(b_val, str):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation! I did try using `typing.SupportsFloat` but it didn't work. I wanted to use `isinstance(a_val, float)` but it doesn't work when `a_val = 123` (an int). Your answer is probably the solution i need.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution with checking `isinstance(a_val, Number)` was close. You just need to change `Number` to `Real` from the `numbers` module. [Real](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real) numbers support conversion to float so it is the right type to check. And the warning is gone. Full code sample:

```
from numbers import Real
import math

a_val = '123'
b_val = 123.4

if isinstance(a_val, Real) and isinstance(b_val, Real):
    is_close = math.isclose(a_val, b_val, abs_tol=0.5)
```